# UWP navigation memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, uwp, navigation

We have noticed that our UWP apps have memory leaks. I have investigated it and found out that when navigating to new pages, the memory gets higher and doesn't seem to go down by much even when GC runs.

I have put together a small repro that consists of two pages:

1. MainPage

```xml
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="navigateButton" Content="Navigate" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="NavigateButton_Click" />

        <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" IsNavigationStackEnabled="False"
               Padding="10" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```cs
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NavigateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1), null, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
        }
    }
```

2. Page1:

```xml
<Page>
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="100" ItemHeight="60">
        <Button Padding="20, 10" Content="Hello!"/>
        <Button Padding="20, 10" Content="Hello!"/>
        <Button Padding="20, 10" Content="Hello!"/>
        <Button Padding="20, 10" Content="Hello!"/>
        <Button Padding="20, 10" Content="Hello!"/>

        <!-- And 25 more buttons here -->
    </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
</Page>
```

```cs
    public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        ~Page1()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Page dead :(");
        }
    }
```

The full source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/encrypt0r/UwpMemoryLeak).

And you can see [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elES9hkT9ok) of the repro.

I have also tried out setting [Frame.IsNavigationStackEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.isnavigationstackenabled) to false, it doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: An image of memory use after clicking on the Navigate button for a while]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 1803 because I have not the latest 1809 but I think it works the same,

In the code of Page 1:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        System.GC.Collect();
    }
```

It is another way to check if the App has to dispose the Pages. and it works.

Comment: Thank you for you time. Do you mean I should call GC.Cllect() on every page or just do that to see if the page is correctly disposed?

Comment: I tried it out and indeed, memory consumption increases at a much slower pace, but it still does increase and it doesn't seem to be reclaimed. I will try it out in other apps to see if it solves the problem. Although I don't like invoking GC explicitly to be honest.

Comment: Well, for sure it has to be an internal UWP bug, because the page should be unloaded automatically. Might be it is solved in 1903 because I think in 1803 IsNavigationStackEnabled is a new property but looks like it has no effect.  What I usually do is having one instance of one kind of page and just change the viewmodel. Depends a lot of the application environment.

Comment: Yes IsNavigationStackEnabled is addd in 1809. That shared page instance and switching VMs seems like a pretty good approach.